# To leave before the end of notice period

Tags: notice-period

I was not happy in my current team at work because of the behavior of my lead and, luck, just after the break I was approached by the resourcing office to see if I would be interested in moving to a different team that needed someone.

My current lead was not happy to let me leave, but I said that I was actually starting to consider leaving the office all together, and therefore it was not really making sense as a decision to force me to stay put, as the office is quite short on people.

It seemed agreed that i would stay a few days more days to tie loose ends on my current project and move on, but now i just realised that my current lead is forcing to keep me behind my back, arguing with the top management that he cannot do the project without me... I suppose he expect that i would need a few weeks before i find a new job and then another few weeks of notice period, kind of hoping to keep me "hostage" of his team for that much longer...

However I am already at my second round of interview in a different firm, and i might just have an offer before the end of next week.

Considering the shitty attitude of the lead, I am considering quitting and leaving with immediate effect, without working during my notice period (which is a month).

What would happen if i do so?

Comment: Stick to the terms of your contract and follow them to the letter.   You might need a reference some day.

Comment: Dont abandon. Later in your career the new firms do background verification and audit of your past employers. One bad feedback will make you lose the new job. My lead fired a lady; and also gave her a bad feedback when the new firm did verification. She lost the job even though offer letter was given

Comment: where do you work? what happens 100% depends on where you work.

Comment: Totally depends on your location and your contract. I'd discuss it with my union lawyers.

How about contacting the top management to try and play team leads games back at him? Might also be a way to alert them of his shitty ways.

Comment: It seems that you are not actually leaving the company, but one team within the company. In that case any notice periods are completely irrelevant. If one team wants you, and the company agrees, then you can leave the old team immediately. Notice period is only for leaving the whole company.

Answer (score 10):

> What would happen if i do so?

That depends on a lot on your local labor laws. Most likely you would be in breach of contract. You may want to consult with a local labor lawyer what the consequences could be and how likely they are.

It would certainly burn bridges with your current employer and reflect badly on your ethics and professionalism. It's possible that even a new prospective employer would take issue with this: if you are doing it to your old employer you probably will do it to them too.

I recommend against this. A month is not all that long and you can just switch to "cruising" mode.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how you can keep an employee against his will, and expect a good quality of work. Cruising mode it is!

Answer (score 7):

> Considering the shitty attitude of the lead, I am considering quitting and leaving with immediate effect, without working during my notice period (which is a month).

I would suggest you don't do this just because some coworker's bad attitude.

Put your name and professionalism first, and hand in and serve your notice period like you agreed to. This person may be "pushing" for you to stay, but at the end you still have the choice to stay or leave, regardless of what this person does or how hard they cry.

> What would happen if i do so?

That would reflect badly on you, and may be an undesired ending for your work relationship with this company. Why burn bridges with the company solely on a single coworker's attitude.

Answer (score 1):

In Europe, not honoring your notice period might even have economic repercussions, so think about it very hard, read your contract and get informed about labor laws.

Don't just do it on a whim, it might have quite dire consequences.

Also, as others have already said, leaving a company on such bad terms is never a good idea in general.
Always try to act professionally, even when the other party doesn't.

Comment: In Europe, any company taking civil action against an employee leaving before his notice period, would be instantly dropped due to abusiveness/excessiveness right away, by any European civil court. Your comment does not reflect reality.

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis I am *obviously* not talking about "taking civil action". Companies won't do that. They don't need to do that. They can (and will) do other things, such as withhold bonuses, or even ask them back (I've seen that happen), and other things like that. *Your* comment does not reflect reality.

Answer (score -1):

Don't be pressurised into doing something rash.  Instead set out clearly what your red lines are.  By all means be frank about the cause of the strife: i.e. Team Lead's specific behaviour.  You may get called names in return, but quite likely the rest of the team are silently suffering and will cautiously support you.  Obviously your plan is to exit, one way or another, from this situation but *gracefully*.

Answer (score -2):

If you have an agreement to change teams by a certain date, I'd wait until that date is up before leaving.

The posturing done by your current lead may not matter much.

If the organisation goes back on its word, I think you could probably violate the notice period, and I'm doubtful a judge would rule against you.

You should study your contract carefully, and also local labour laws before doing such a thing.

Comment: Whether or not to actually break notice is a legal issue. I would discuss it with a lawyer (or know local custom on it well) before doing it.

If your employer is treating you badly, and likely not producing a nice reference anyway.. Take any legally sound actions that are good for you, and dont look back, morally speaking.